# Survey Analysis Software

Tags: open-source, crosstab, spss

I am looking for a software to analyze survey data online.

My input should be SPSS file or anything similar (I don't mind writing a small tool to format the input, we enter the data using a proprietary software).

The idea is that the administrator should be able to upload the survey data to the website, and the users should be able to do simple analysis/data extraction.

The analysis should mostly be creating targets and generating cross tab reports.

I prefer open source software so I can write customized reports within the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a wikipedia article that answers my question:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence_tools